# Every row given must be either null or an array with google chart line

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a line from google chart samples and when I used th  data.addRows to read my data number from Mysql database it gives me `Every row given must be either null or an array.` but if I put the data manually the line will draw but fetch from database table gives me error.

My code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

  function drawLineColors() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'id');
   data.addColumn('number', 'temp');
   data.addColumn('number', 'hum');

    data.addRows([  ['id', 'temp', 'hum']


     <?php

       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               echo " 
     [".$row['id'].",".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
           }

       }

     ?>
       ]);

      var options = {
       hAxis: {
        title: 'Time'
       },
       vAxis: {
        title: 'Popularity'
      },
      colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
     };

    var chart = new 

  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already defined your row column names, so you should remove the first array in `addRows`.

Change:

```
data.addRows([  ['id', 'temp', 'hum']
```

To:

```
data.addRows([
```

Comment: Actually the comma is within `[".$row['id'].",".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";` but BTW I added as your suggestion but gives me error `Type mismatch. Value id does not match type number in column index 0` !

Comment: But the comma was at the end, not the start. I don't think you even want the first array. I'll update my answer